# Scalar Triple Product proof

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, inner-products

I wanted to prove that if we change order of vectors involved in a scalar triple product in a cyclic fashion , then the product remain same .
I want an elegant proof of it involving simple algebra of vectors only .

I have already proved it by showing that the volume of parallelopied remains same after the cyclic shift .

I also proved by considering

**A** = a**i** + b**j** + c**k**

**B** = d**i** + e**j** + f**k**

**C** = g**i** + h**j** + p**k**

Now by expanding the scalar triple product by determinants and arranging in both cases, I can easily prove that it remains same .
But what I am asking is an more algebraic and elegant way . I mean , without just simply expanding and without geometrical interpretation. I meant , I want a prove involving only vectors like using properties of vectors .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbf a\times \mathbf c$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf a$, we have :
$$\mathbf a \cdot (\mathbf b \times \mathbf c) = \mathbf a \cdot (( \mathbf a + \mathbf b)\times \mathbf c)$$

Likewise, we have $(\mathbf a + \mathbf b) \cdot ((\mathbf a + \mathbf  b) \times \mathbf c) = 0$. Combining both equations we get :
\begin{align}
\mathbf  a \cdot (\mathbf b \times \mathbf c) &= - \mathbf b \cdot (( \mathbf  a  +\mathbf b)\times \mathbf c) \\
&= - \mathbf b\cdot( \mathbf a\times \mathbf c) \\
&= \mathbf b\cdot (\mathbf c \times \mathbf a)
\end{align}

Comment: Wow thanks . In last , can you give me any tip that how you to prove things like this ? Or will I learn to prove like this after experience of years only . Thanks once again .

Comment: One think that might help is to write down the things that may be useful for a given problem : the hypotheses, the conclusion we want to reach and the properties and theorem that are related. Here, you could list the algebraic properties of the cross and dot product. After that, discriminating between relevant and irrelevant properties and choosing how to combine them to form a proof comes down to experience.